# php mysql_real_escape_string conversion to mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi im currently learning php and mysql a tutorial i am following uses the now out of date mysql_real_escape_string ive read the manual on mysqli's version of it but just cant really figure out how i would do something like the code below.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($POST['username']);
```

any help in converting this over to mysqli and any tips are greatly apreciated

Comment: You'd use prepared statements which escape for you or: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Have a look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: It's basically the same except that you pass the connection object as the first argument.

Comment: [This Q&A is well worth a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). Use prepared statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries

Comment: sorry for the duplicate i did try searching but i guess i was being too specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thank you this approach worked a treat

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($POST['username']);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the above notation is the Object Orientated notation. (This will confuse anyone trying to code SQL connections procedurally.)

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but i had already tried that unfortunatly i keep getting Undefined variable error

Answer (score 0):

First, create your connection and store it in a variable $link.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_table");
```

Use this $link as the first parameter in mysqli_real_escape_string.

```
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $POST['username']);
```

Reference: [Example of mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#refsect1-mysqli.real-escape-string-examples)